# auto formatting 10 digits phone number as entered in the input field

Tags: javascript, forms, autoformatting

In the logic is for auto formatting 10 digits phone number into the following format (xxx) 234-3456

```
<div class="field-group" style="align-items: center;">
    <div>
        <se-singleselect selected="{{phoneItem.phoneTypeId}}" fieldvalue="phoneTypeId" fieldname="name" desc="Phone Type" datasrc="{{_phoneTypes}}" id="phoneTypeSelect"></se-singleselect>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="phoneNumber" class="phone" name="phoneNumber" maxlength="14" placeholder="(xxx) xxx-xxxx" on-input="_allowNumbersCharsOnly" on-change="_formatPhoneNumber" value="{{phoneItem.phoneNumber::input}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript logic to format

```
_formatPhoneNumber(digit) {
    let number = digit.target.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
    if (number.length == 10) {
        number = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1) $2-$3");
    }
    console.log(number) // (123) 456-6789
}
```

console.log shows the correct format in Console.

Comment: so what is the issue? You do not set the value back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried by replacing the line

```
console.log(number)
```

With

```
Document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value = number
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Since I have very less contribution in forum thus replying with an answer.

```js
let phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phoneNumber');
phoneNumber.addEventListener('change',_formatPhoneNumber);
phoneNumber.addEventListener('keyup',_formatPhoneNumber);

function _formatPhoneNumber(evt) {
    let number = evt.target.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
    if (number.length == 10) {
        number = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1) $2-$3");
    }
    //console.log(number) // (123) 456-6789
    evt.target.value = number;
}
```

```html
<div class="field-group" style="align-items: center;">
    <div>
        <se-singleselect selected="{{phoneItem.phoneTypeId}}" fieldvalue="phoneTypeId" fieldname="name" desc="Phone Type" datasrc="{{_phoneTypes}}" id="phoneTypeSelect"></se-singleselect>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="phoneNumber" class="phone" name="phoneNumber" maxlength="14" placeholder="(xxx) xxx-xxxx" on-input="_allowNumbersCharsOnly" on-change="_formatPhoneNumber" >
    </div>
</div>
```